# I want import python code in htm file with django

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

```
{% for post in posts %}
{{post.name}}
{{post.content}}
{% endfor %}
```

I created html file and i'm trying to use python code in html but `{{}}` `{%%}` tags not working. It show me my code like a html p tag
 Only i see this on browser not working codes. where is the problem library?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation is correct the way you did, maybe the error is in the view, see this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/